# многопользовательский сценарий

Tags: php, mysql, алгоритм, while

есть блок кода (назовем его $foo->bar() ) который должен выполнится один раз и только один раз. как это организовать в многопользовальском сценарии?

поясню, есть сценарий space.php
к нему обращаются множество пользователей, в конкретном случае 20 человек.

мы проверяем, все ли пользователи дали ответ
и если все - выполняем код $foo->bar() 
если же нет - пользователю предлагается дать ответ или ждать других участников если ответ дан.

по сути мне нужно вполнять  $foo->bar() только когда последний пользователь даст ответ, либо по истечению тайм-аута

по окончанию работы $foo->bar() начинаем новый раунд, и все пользователи снова могут дать ответ.
в ходе работы $foo->bar() есть логирование его выполнения, исходя из которого видно, что код инициализируется несколько раз.

как я вижу проблему:
пользователи (user1, user2, ...., user20) обращаются к сценарию space.php
user1, user2 и user3 дали ответ, ждут, ждут, ждут, обновляя страницу каждый раз
$foo->bar() не может быть выполнен пока не дал последний пользователь user10.
user1, user2 и user3 обновляют и ждут
user10 дает наконец ответ и запускает $foo->bar()
user1 и user3 обновляя страницу так же запускают $foo->bar() клонируя процесс. поскольку первый процесс еще не был выполнен, то и условия для запуска соблюдены.

ОК. делаем костыль.
в базе данных , в таблицу сценария, объединяющего пользователей, добавил поле startrun default 0
и поред запуском $foo->bar() проверяем значение startrun:
если 1 - процесс уже запущен. ожидаем выполнения.
если 0 - устанавливаем startrun = 1, дабы предотвратить клонирование процесса, и запускаем процесс $foo->bar()

проблема в том, что костыль не работает. исходя из логов код по прежнему несколько раз запускается.

итак, как выполнить код, один только раз, в многопользовательском сценарии?

Comment: У вас выполняется `$foo->bar()` когда в базе значение 1 независимо ни от чего? Ищите косяк в своём коде. Если же по логам видно, что  `$foo->bar()` несколько раз одновременно, когда в базе значение 0, то тут проблема с одновременным доступом. Лечится созданием транзакции, блокировкой строки.

Comment: я немного поправил и дополнил пост

Comment: Делается это через транзакции. Запускаете транзакцию. Берёте из базы кол-во ответов. Если оно совпадает с кол-вом пользователей, выполняете `$foo->bar()`. Завершаете транзакцию.

Comment: транзакции? пока не могу сказать, подойдет ли мне это решение.

Comment: Мне предлагали сделать сокет-сервер или демона, который работал бы в фоне, исключая вызов пользователем. Ищу варианты, должно же быть что-то проще!

Comment: Транзакция - 2 строчки в коде. Демон и сокет-сервер - овер дохрена строк кода. Какой вариант лучше?